# How to add 2D Overlay Exit Button when User Enters into VR in WebVR?

Tags: aframe

I am new to Aframe and try to put 2D Overlay menu to exit from VR mode when a user enters into VR Mode.

What I want is exactly the same as given in krpano examples [here](https://krpano.com/releases/1.20.9/viewer/krpano.html?xml=examples/blending-demo/blending-demo.xml).

[Krpano Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdIjo.jpg)

I added a-entity and write code on that. It worked but I want a 2D overlay kind of in webVR.

any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two ways of doing this:

1. Create your UI using regular HTML markup and superimpose it on the WebVR canvas.
2. Create your UI elements in Aframe, but parent them to the camera object so they don't move.

Here's a simple example using both techniques. I've applied `pointer-events: none` to the HTML elements to stop them getting in the way of mouse interactions with the 3D scene, but you can make your UI items clickable if you like. When you create UI items as 3D elements, they'll respond to the scene lighting, which you may prefer. Getting them to respond to mouse clicks is a lot harder, though.

```css
.uiwrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.uiblock {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 4vmin;
  width: 10em;
  height: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 100, 0.5);
  padding: 1em 2em;
  margin-top: 20vh;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  /* ignore console warnings in snippet view */
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<a-scene>
  <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
  <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
  <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D"></a-cylinder>
  <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
  <a-sky color="#666"></a-sky>
  <a-entity light="type: directional; color: #FFF; intensity: 2" position="1 2 3"></a-entity>
  <a-camera position="0 1 0">
    <a-plane position="0 0 -.11" width=".1" height=".02" color="rgb(0, 0, 100)" opacity="0.5"></a-plane>
    <a-entity position="0 0 -.1" text="color: #fff; width: 0.16; align: center; value: Linked to camera"></a-entity>
  </a-camera>
</a-scene>
<div class="uiwrapper">
  <div class="uiblock">
    HTML overlay
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: afaik the HTML overlay won't be visible in "VR" mode https://glitch.com/edit/#!/aframe-gftruj-vrmodehtml?path=index.html%3A30%3A18

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski Ah, OK. I will have to ask Santa for an Oculus Prime :-)

Comment: it's fun :D but you can check it on you phone (when you click "vr" - the HTML overlay should dissapear. I'm not sure what WebXR magic is going on there though)